# Installshield Express append Config name to msi filename

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installshield, slowcheetah

Right now I am using vs 2015 and Flexera installshield for a windows service. I am also using slowcheetah for xml transformations.

Right now i am outputting a msi file like `FileName.msi` but I would like the ability to have different names for each config. For instance I have three configs that output the SingleImage option, the Release, debug, and the Qa version. I would like these configs to output  `FileNameRelease.msi`, `FileNameDebug.msi`, and `FileNameQa.msi`.

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installshield Express doesn't have this capability.

Answer (score -1):

Specify an alternate **MSI Package File Name** on each [General Tab for a Product Configuration](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/ProdConfigGeneralTab.htm). Note that a minor upgrade must share the same file name as the original install to avoid error 1316, so don't mix and match the resulting files.

Comment: So how do you find the general tab for a product configuration? Do I need Professional or premier to see it?

Comment: Ok I think I found it in '(6)Prepare for Release'->'Releases'. But the only "configuration" I see is 'Express'. Which means nothing to me and I don't see any way to add configurations.

Comment: Yes, this answer is specific to pro/prem. I guessed incorrectly due to the tag and problem description provided.

Comment: Ok, so the tags are correct, but in the past they would not have been.

Comment: Yes, as long as you aren't using the limited edition (it has its own tag). Regardless, mentioning in your description the project type and/or product edition would have avoided the confusion.